# PropertyGrid issue in NET 5

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a winform project compiled to NET 5. It has a PropertyGrid element. When the project runs [image: PropertyGrid in NET 5]

We can PropertyGrid doesn't show values. We only see when click in property. If I build in NET Core 3.1 the result is the following:

[image: Result with NET Core 3.1]

It is working fine. It looks a bug. Have anyone the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have experienced the same issue. It looks like a bug where rendering an unfocused / view-only Value in the 2nd column always occurs at `(0, 0)` / in the upper-left corner of the entire Client area.